# converting string euler number to int in c#

Tags: c#

i have an account number that is stored in as a query string. How do i convert 6.21129e+006 into an actual int

Comment: How do you query that integer… It looks like a `double`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can parse the string as a double, and later cast the double to integer.

However, casting from double to integer is subject to precision lost or even integer overflow

```
string s = "6.21129e+006";
double d = Double.Parse(s);
Console.WriteLine(s);

int i = (int)d;
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're sure the result will be convertible to integer you can parse it as double and cast to int:

```
[Test]
public void Example()
{
    int num = (int)double.Parse("6.21129e+006");

    Assert.That(num, Is.EqualTo(6211290));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`NumberStyles.Float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) argument on the [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c09yxbyt.aspx) method:

```
var n = int.Parse("6.21129e+006", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

Note that this will fail if the parsed number is a double, e.g. `5e-1` which is `0.5`.